# Boost and Telegram API: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, api, boost, telegram

I am trying to build Telegram API to C++ from here https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp
And it need Boost libs. I installed it, builded solution with CMake, but then I try to build my solution I have a lot of "unresolved external symbot" problems[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are OpenSSL library symbols. boost::asio::ssl requires OpenSSL. See notes at the bottom of this page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html.